# Java generics with Function.apply

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8

I am playing with Java utility functions. I have the following code:

```
public class Checker<T>{

  private T value;
  private Function<T, T> callback;

  private Checker(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static Checker when(String o) {
    return new Checker<String>(o);
  }

  public static Checker when(int o) {
    return new Checker<Integer>(o);
  }

  public Checker then(Function<T, T> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    return this;
  }

  public void execute() {
    if (this.value instanceof String) {
      this.callback.apply("123");
    }
    if (this.value instanceof Integer) {
      this.callback.apply(123);
    }
  }

  Checker.when("123").then(str -> {
    return "";
  }).execute();

  Checker.when(123).then(str -> {
    return "";
  }).execute();
```

Now here I am getting an error for `this.callback.apply("123")` as it requires `T` and cannot cast it to `String`.

Is it possible to have generic return types for `Function<T,T>`? I can send `T`, but then its received as an `Object` in my lambda, but I want as `String` or `Integer`.

Comment: Why would you need to do this `instanceof` chain, rather than simply `this.callback.apply(value)`? Why would you want to pass in `123` specifically? Why not just make `value` a compatible instance of `123`?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made some changes in your `Checker` class which make sense to me. I eliminated all the raw types, and I used the `value` member in `execute`. I added a return type of `execute`, in order to be able to print its result.

```
class Checker<T>{

  private T value;
  private Function<T, T> callback;

  private Checker(T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static Checker<String> when(String o) {
    return new Checker<>(o);
  }

  public static Checker<Integer> when(int o) {
    return new Checker<>(o);
  }

  public Checker<T> then(Function<T, T> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    return this;
  }

  public T execute() {
    return this.callback.apply(value);
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Checker.when("123").then(str -> {
      return "." + str + ".";
    }).execute();

    Checker.when(123).then(i -> {
      return i + 100;
    }).execute();
  }
}
```

Now when you check your class with:

```
System.out.println (Checker.when("123").then(str -> "." + str + ".").execute());
System.out.println (Checker.when(123).then(i -> i + 100).execute());
```

You get:

```
.123.
223
```

Comment: you could replace `Function<T,T>` with `UnaryOperator<T>` and also infer the types via `return new Checker<>(o)`

Comment: You could also replace `str -> {return "." + str + ".";}` with just `str -> "." + str + "."`

Comment: When `then` is called multiple times, all but the last function will be lost. If `then` is never called, you’ll get a `NullPointerException`. It would be better to initialize `callback` with `Function.identity()` and implement `then` with `this.callback = this.callback.andThen(callback);`…

Comment: @Eugene: but there is no advantage in using `UnaryOperator` here. It would just add *restrictions* to the code. It would be more useful to go into the other direction: `public <R> Checker<R> then(Function<? super T, ? extends R> callback) { … }`

Comment: @Holger agreed, I have no idea why the OP choose `Function<T,T>`, I was just respecting his choice here

Answer (score 3):

This code can be even further simplified, like this:

```
static class Checker<T> {

    private final T value;

    private UnaryOperator<T> callback;

    private Checker(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <T> Checker<T> when(T o) {
        return new Checker<>(o);
    }

    public Checker<T> then(UnaryOperator<T> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        return this;
    }

    public T execute() {
        return this.callback.apply(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggested the code can be simplified, but why not make the calls chainable and also the class final, that way you'd have a simple and clean model:

```
final class Checker<T> {

    private final T value;

    private final UnaryOperator<T> callback;

    private Checker(T value, UnaryOperator<T> callback) {
        this.value = value;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public static <T> Checker<T> when(T t) {
        return new Checker<>(t, UnaryOperator.identity());
    }

    public Checker<T> then(UnaryOperator<T> callback) {
        return new Checker<>(value, t -> callback.apply(this.callback.apply(t)));
    }

    public T execute() {
        return callback.apply(value);
    }
}
```

Rather than returning `this` in the `then()` this approach returns a completly new Checker-instance